# How to determine which value of a grouping in shown in Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2015

I have a report, in which the highest level of detail produces 2 rows of the dataset, which I need to show grouped. The grouping works fine, but a few of the columns still contain different values; how do I tell the report which value it should display?

Example:
The user wants each row of the report to be grouped by Brand name. 1 Brand can have multiple agreement that are relevant for the numbers to be shown in the report. The numbers can be aggregated, but there is also data that has changed with the new agreement, so only the most recent version needs to be shown

Agreement 1: item-A, item-B, value-A
Agreement 2: item-B, item-C, value B

Grouping by Brand should show:
Agreement: item-B, item-C, sum(value-A+B). But I do not know how to tell the report which items to show.

SQL for the dataset shouldn't be modified in order to maintain option in report to show both rows separate as well.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Thank you

Comment: That depends on the format and value of `Item-A`, `Item-B` and `Value-A` (For `String`or `Number`you can choose different aggregate functions, which might help or not). Do you have maybe a minimal example of this data? It would be best if you add a table with the raw data and a table that shows the end result.

Comment: The aggregation of the Value-A (which are Numbers) is working as expected. Item-A and B though are Strings, for which I want to choose what to show.
Example of the data:
row 1: cre-h&m-045, 1000
row 2: cre-h&m-37/38, null

In this case, the grouped result should show:
row1: cre-h&m-045, 1000

Answer (score 0):

If it is a string you propably can just use the aggregations `First()` and `Last()`.

But there is a workaround. You have to define a calculated field in your dataset and write your desired expression into it. Think of it like a rating system. The biggest value is the value you will chose in the grouping, because in the grouping you just have to use `Max()`then.

For example as calculated field (This is a example for strings, you can also convert in double and use > or <, that depens on your variations from the value of ItemA):

```
'Calculated field name: CustomField
=Switch(Fields!ItemA.Value = Nothing, 1,
        Fields!ItemA.Value = "500", 2, 
        Fields!ItemA.Value = "1000", 3)
```

Now add your grouping and chose the calculated field in the groupings like this:

```
Max(Fields!CustomField.Value)
```

Then hide the `Fields!CustomField.Value` and show the `Fields!ItemA.Value`. This way it will display the row value of `Fields!ItemA.Value` and you custom grouped after `Fields!CustomField.Value`.